# Change pagination HTML on Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

Is there a way to change the HTML given by the method render(), on Laravel's pagination?

Note: I solved this creating a helper that uses `str_replace`, but I don't think this is the most correct way...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a CustomPaginator Class that extends

```
Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapThreePresenter
```

And override its methods.

I needed a custom class attached pagination with 1 onEachSide instead of 3.

So I did this:

https://gist.github.com/aykutcan/495d43041571854a7507

Answer (score 0):

I've found this library -
[Landish/Pagination](https://github.com/Landish/Pagination)
- that already brings some paginators and lets you easily create your own.